# Relation between Foreground Services and PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK

Tags: android, service, power-management

I know foreground services have "unlikely to kill" behavior. According to Android documentation:

> It is still theoretically possible for the service to be killed under
>   extreme memory pressure from the current foreground application, but
>   in practice this should not be a concern.

I think this solves the low memory concern for most cases. But I cannot find any documentation on whether the CPU goes to sleep while a foreground service is running.

1. Does a foreground service automatically acquire **PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK** or one has to call it explicitly if needed?
2. Is there any way to check/log which application/services are using PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK?

Answer (score 2):

Android **foreground** service and **PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK** have nothing to do with each other.

Foreground service -> it tells the OS to put your service in the highest priority queue. If OS needs memory for any reason, it will kill your service at LAST, and it will start with queue at lowest priority (I believe there are 5 priority queues, and foreground is the highest).

PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK -> it tell the OS not to put the CPU to sleep when device goes to sleep (whenever this happen).

So, even if you have a foreground service, if device goes to sleep the cpu might go to sleep as well (it might not if some other app acquired a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK).
I don't think there is a way to check which applications acquired wake lock programmatically, but you can plug your device to DDMS and you will see PowerManager logs when someone acquires a wake_lock.

Hope it helps !